# How to apply a class to a label with the attribute for with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code

```
 <label for="docFile">
   <i style="cursor: pointer;" class="material-icons">search</i>
</label>
```

How to apply css class with Jquery in to label "docFile" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$("label[for='docFile']")` as your Selector.

```
$("label[for='docFile']").addClass("newClass");
```

Comment: it didn't work I ran it via console and it didn't work

Comment: This example assumes you have jQuery already loaded. It may not work in Console.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do the job.

`$("label[for='docFile']").addClass("yourclass");`

Comment: it didn't work I ran it via console and it didn't work

Comment: have you included jquery to your project ?